# How do I view contents of incoming bindRequests to Active Directory DS?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2016, schannel

I have a full fledged AD DS running on Windows server 2016. I have a spring app which I am using to authenticate against my active directory database using a simple authentication bind over a ssl connection. I want to examine the contents of all incoming bindRequests to the AD server, whether they succeed or fail.

Furthermore, I want to troubleshoot whether the name form in the bind request is being matched against the CN or the displayName attribute of my user object. My CN and displayName are exactly the same for some users and different for some users so I want to view logs or something similar to be sure.

If Schannel is the solution for this, what should I use to filter the logs?

Any pointers would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I've heard of AD DCs matching the bind name against _either_ the CN or the displayName at all? If you bind to a DN as is standard, then the full exact DN is matched. The only AD-specific alternatives are the UPN or the sAMAccountName.

Comment: You can turn on diagnostic logging to get more details about the connection: https://kb.wisc.edu/iam/page.php?id=35143

Comment: Thanks @twconnell that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll just add my comment as an answer then ;)

You can turn on diagnostic logging to get more details about the connection:

https://kb.wisc.edu/iam/page.php?id=35143